# Java how to initialize two dimensional array elements to null

Tags: java, arrays

I want create an 2d Integer array like `Integer[][]table`, and instead of initializing the element to 0 by default, how can I make initialize it as null instead? For example:

```
if (table[row][col] == null) {
    table[row][col] = value;
}
```

Instead of looping each element and set it to null, is there a quick way to init to null?

Comment: An `int` cannot have a null value. Only objects (including `Integer` objects) can be `null`.

Comment: `int` has default value. it is `0`.

Comment: Use `Integer` instead

Comment: `Integer` arrays are initialized with nulls by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the value of a primitive variable to `null`. If you need `null` values, you have to use a reference type.

`Integer` is the reference type you want to use instead of `int`:

```
Integer[][] table
```

When an `Integer[][]` array like this is created, its elements' values will be `null` (because `null` is the default value for all reference types):

```
Integer[][] table = new Integer[2][2]; //All 4 elements will be null
```

Comment: I edited the question, instead looping each element and set it to null, is there a quick way to init to null?

Comment: @Raj If the type of an array isn't basic type, it will be null as default.

Answer (score 1):

use Integer instead of int, so Integer will treat as object and object default value is null.

**Integer[][] arr = new Integer[2][2];**//initialized like that

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others